# Prevent automatic line breaks in a <code> tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, format, whitespace

I have a html `code` tag, wrapped in in a `pre` tag with fixed width and am getting ugly automatic line breaks:

[image: Ugly line breaks!]

What I want to achieve is, that the text is NOT automatically broken on spaces, but when I add a `white-space: nowrap` to the `code` element, the whole thing collapses to a single line, so all \n and \r characters are ignored as well:

[image: Single line]

Does anyone have an idea how to prevent automatic line breaks, but keep the intended line breaks?

Comment: Could you put some simple code of what you have done so that we can inspect.

Comment: `pre` markup implies that the text is rendered as-is, with no wrapping and no line breaks except as in the source code or caused by markup. So there must be something in your code that prevents that. Please post a demo that demonstrates what is really going on (preferably, minimal HTML and CSS that actually shows the problem).

Comment: You were right - it was a style inside twitters bootstrap framework that caused the problem. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem was caused by twitter bootstrap.
For whatever reason, they added the following styles to the code tag:

```
white-space:pre;
white-space:pre-wrap;
word-break:break-all;
word-wrap:break-word;
```

By overwriting the styles with:

```
white-space: pre;
word-break: normal;
word-wrap: normal;
```

The problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YK4ES/)

```
.content pre
{
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
    white-space: -pre-wrap;
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */  
}
```